# I can't seem to apply Jquery to my Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone suggest me a solution please? I've been trying half an hour to get jQuery ready and working for my Visual Studio but it does not work. I can't really be specific because i also don't know why.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $("#square").animate({ left: '500px' }, slow);
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
    #square{
        border: solid; border-color: aqua; border-width: 1px; background-color: skyblue; width: 125px; height: 125px; text-align:center;
    }
</style>

<body>
<div id="square">Focus on me!</div>
<div> <button>Click me</button> </div>
```

Comment: wow, jQuery is a JavaScript include in an HTML file, I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: You can be more specific: what, *specifically*, are you trying to achieve? what *specific* steps have you taken? what *specific* results/errors, if any, are you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add jquery to your page. You can add jQuery in two ways :

1. Download the jQuery library from [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com/download/)
2. Include jQuery from a CDN, like Google

The jQuery library is a single JavaScript file, and you reference it with the HTML  tag :

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And for CDN :

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

then write your code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   alert("Hello there!")

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this piece of code above the closing `body` tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now you have successfully added jQuery!

Comment: I did do that too but my code does not work. So i figured it had to something to do with my Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you check the error console to see if you have any errors?

Comment: Oh it says this:
The program '[4496] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[4496] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Can you trying using the `CTRL` + `F5` combination te clear your cache and rerun the application?